MudBlazor - MudGrid and data paging with Blazor
Ive just started using the MudDataGrid in the MudBlazor componet set and Im trying to get serverside data retrieval and paging working.
I found an excellent example here
Mudgrid and serverside data
And by following it, I managed to get the functionality to work.  I do have one problem though, for no reason that I can see, the forward/backward/first/last buttons are always disabled ! Ive inspected the html and this is what I see


<button type="button" disabled class="mud-button-root mud-icon-button mud-ripple mud-ripple-icon mud-flip-x-rtl" _bl_9bb473ae-a2b8-457a-8564-cc4d1a6ca9c7=""><span class="mud-icon-button-label"><!--!--><svg class="mud-icon-root mud-svg-icon mud-icon-size-medium" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><!--!--><path d="M18.41 16.59L13.82 12l4.59-4.59L17 6l-6 6 6 6zM6 6h2v12H6z"></path><path d="M24 24H0V0h24v24z" fill="none"></path></svg></span></button>



this is my grid setup, its working perfectly, just no enabled paging buttons


<MudDataGrid ServerData="LoadGridData" T="AgencyGridViewModel" @ref="_dataGrid">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Agencies</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="_searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                      AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="MudBlazor.Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.AgencyName" Title="Agency Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.AgencyAdd1" Title="Address 1" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.AgencyAdd2" Title="Address 2" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.AgencyTown_City" Title="Town/City" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.AgencyPostcode" Title="Postcode" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="AgencyGridViewModel" Disabled="false" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>



is this a known issue, or am I missing something, hopefully someone will have an answer
**Update
Ive spent the best part of a day on this and no progress, ALL the examples show this as the way to implement pagination control but it doesn't work, the buttons for moving through pages are ALWAYS disabled


<PagerContent>
    <MudDataGridPager T="AgencyGridViewModel" Disabled="false" />
</PagerContent>



This is the code Ive used to retrieve data and populate the DataGrid
private async Task<GridData<AgencyGridViewModel>> LoadGridData(GridState<AgencyGridViewModel> state)
{
    var result = await AgencyService.GetPagedAsync(new PagedMessageRequest() { Page = state.Page, PageSize = state.PageSize }, this.CancelToken);
    Agencies = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AgencyDto>, IEnumerable<AgencyGridViewModel>>(result.Result);
    GridData<AgencyGridViewModel> data = new()
    {
        Items = Agencies.AsQueryable(),
        TotalItems = result.PageCount
    };
   return data;
}

Here's a screenshot of the data grid paging buttons, as you can se they are disabled despite the grid having data and multiple pages
Can anyone help ?


Can you show your LoadGridData Method? Are you setting the property TotalItems?
Maybe you get less or equals as many items as the size of the page

see the update above

there are currently 23 records in the underlying table and the page size is set to 10, so that would equal 3 pages, which is being correctly reported

Doh !!! just realised what the problem is ! The DataGrid does its own page number calculation based on page size and total record count, Ive also done that calculation manually and assigned the value to the TotalItems property, I've changed the code and now it works !
GridData<AgencyGridViewModel> data = new()
{
    Items = Agencies.AsQueryable(),
    TotalItems = result.Count //-> NOT my manually calculated PageCount property
};

